# React Native: 'android.bluetooth.bluetoothadapter.isEnabled()' on a null reference

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eddystone

I am working on a React-Native app that relies on Bluetooth for some of its functionality and as far as I understand, Android Studio's emulator does not support Bluetooth. The package I am using is [react-native-eddystone](https://github.com/lg2/react-native-eddystone) which is used to work with Bluetooth low energy devices. When I start the app on my phone it prompts me to allow the usage of Bluetooth and works fine but when I use the emulator it crashes from the start. Here is the `AndroidManifets.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" />
</manifest>
```

And here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Edit: The error occurs here in EddystoneModule.java:

```java
  @ReactMethod
  public void startScanning() {
    ScanFilter serviceFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(SERVICE_UUID).build();

    ScanFilter configurationFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(CONFIGURATION_UUID).build();

    final List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add(serviceFilter);
    filters.add(configurationFilter);

    ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();

    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) { // <--- here bluethoothAdapter is null
      Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
      getCurrentActivity().startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 8123);
    }

    // start scanning
    scanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    scanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback);
  }
```

Comment: So this means the ReactNative plugin you are using does not do error checking that the device it is running on supports bluetooth.  And as a result, when you run it on an emulator it crashes.  This is a flaw in the plugin -- it does not support running on an emulator.

Comment: Just simply add the code to get the adapter from bluetoothManager:                                                                                                        
      ```val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(context,BluetoothManager::class.java)
val bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager?.adapter```